# css have a listbox i need it to on select neither changes text color as active or inactive, focus or not focused. its click add, click add

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a listbox, I need it to on select neither change text color as active or inactive, focus or not focused. Its click add, click add. On this one the text stays white on select, and turns black when click out of the listbox. I need it to stay red and only background to change when its clicked, to show it was clicked, then just go back to black. (Ive been at this for a couple days before asking, might have errors in the code after rewriting it so many times.)

```
<select onclick="" class="sometext" name="sometext" size="5">
    <?php 
        $sql = "select * FROM mom WHERE type='feedme'";
        foreach ($dblsm->query($sql) as $row){

            echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[title]</option>"; 

            /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

        }
    ?>
</select>
```

css

```
/* turn it off completely */
select:active, select:hover, select:focus {
outline: none;
}

select option:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#a81b1b, #000000);
    background-color: #000000 !important; /* for IE */
    color: #a81b1b !important;
    outline: none;
    }

select option:checked, select option:active, select option:disabled {
    background: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
    background-color: #000000 !important; /* for IE */
    color: #a81b1b !important;
    }

.sometext::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}

/* Track */
    .sometext::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
.sometext::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #a81b1b; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

.sometext {
    color: #a81b1b;
    background-color: black;
    width: 225px;
    border: 3px inset;
    border-color: #a81b1b;
    scrollbar-face-color: #367CD2;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #a81b1b;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand your question better now from your comments, I'm not sure how to accomplish this with the default options of a form's select box. What I did come up with for you is a way to get a similar outcome with plain ol' html/js/css and hopefully you can adapt this to your needs:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="redhue">
      <li onClick="changeSelectionTo(this)">1</li>
      <li onClick="changeSelectionTo(this)">2</li>
      <li onClick="changeSelectionTo(this)">3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<script>
  var currentlySelected;
  function changeSelectionTo(item) {
    if(currentlySelected){
      currentlySelected.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    currentlySelected = item;
    item.classList.add("selected");
    console.log(item.innerText);
  }
</script>
<style>
  ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  li:hover,
  .selected {
    background: linear-gradient(#a81b1b, #000000);
    background-color: #000000; /* for IE */
    color: #a81b1b;
  }

  .redhue {
    color: #a81b1b;
    background-color: black;
    width: 225px;
    border: 3px inset;
    border-color: #a81b1b;
    list-style: none;
  }   
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I left the console.log statement to show how to retrieve the list item's value for whatever you would need it for... Hope this helps!

Comment: no then i lost the background color i set. i have it so only the text is wrong. the background(default blue highlight gone) and back ground only changes color atm when u click then all other style is the same. except the text color value defaults to black(active list item, clicked out of list) and white(clicked). text needs to stay red all times. color: #a81b1b !important; doesnt seem to do anything in these cases.

Comment: i dont want the list to show anything was "selected", in the form u can click the same list item many times, to add them to another field. but, the background highlights only once to show it was clicked. then all list items return not "selected". maybe after selecting the item, add it to the field, then somehow unselect it?? lol no idea. but, then i still get the default white text onclick... lol

Comment: Yes, this works exactly as i need thank you very much.